# NoMethodError: undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass for the Chef Zabbix cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

i am using the zabbix cookbook (https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/zabbix) in one of my own cookbook to install the zabbix agent on the nodes via the source. I specify:`include_recipe "zabbix::agent"` and then in the berkshelf of the cookbook.

The issue is that if i execute chef-client manually on the nodes, i see no problem. The chef run completes successfully. It's in the chef run that is started every 30mins that fails with this error.

```
[2015-03-26T18:02:01+00:00] INFO: Sending resource update report (run-id: aa2e95d5-32f5-4185-a049-5ea3808c0522)
[2015-03-26T18:02:02+00:00] ERROR: zabbix_source[install_zabbix_agent] (zabbix::agent_source line 36) had an error: NoMethodError: chef_gem[zabbixapi] (zabbix::_providers_common line 1) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass
[2015-03-26T18:02:02+00:00] ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
[2015-03-26T18:02:02+00:00] ERROR: Sleeping for 1800 seconds before trying again
```

While investigating, i found that the recipe `zabbix/recipes/_providers_common.rb` is the one that install the gem zabbixapi. But this recipe is not called while using only the zabbix::agent recipe, but i do confirm that the gem `zabbixapi` exist in the node at

```
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zabbixapi-0.6.6/lib/zabbixapi
```

I have submitted an issue via github for this cookbook too, but waiting on a response.

PS: chef-client 11.4 in use

Comment: Looks like a localization issue, as per the opscode.. i will post back the solution once, all set (just in case, someone runs into the same/similiar issue)

Answer (score 0):

Created `/etc/default/chef-client` with the below entries

```
#!/bin/bash
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

And sourced it via the `/etc/init.d/chef-client`

```
#added for the zabbix::agent recipe
[ -f /etc/default/chef-client ] && . /etc/default/chef-client
```